# How do I use multiple datepicker interfaces on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple datepickers in my application. However, one of the datepickers should be a month-picker (The ReportPeriod object) while the remaining objects (With Style2 class) should use the default, standardized datepicker. I'm new to Jquery, thanks!

I current have both datepickers loaded in the same script which is likely while the issue is occurring since the most recent attributes applied apparently affect all datepicker objects.

Jquery:

```
$('#ReportPeriod').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        var date = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1);
        period = date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        console.log(period);
        VerifyReportingPeriod(period);
    }
});
$('.Style2').datepicker();
```

HTML:

```
<td class="alignleft"><input type="text" id="ReportPeriod" required class="Style1"/></td>
 <td class="alignleft"><input type="text" id="MissionMilestone1" class="Style2" /></td>
```

CSS:

```
.Style1 {
    width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 30px;
}

.Style2 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar { (I want this only applied to my ReportPeriod Object)
    display: none;
}
```

The current code shows the monthpicker displaying properly, but the regular datepicker (w/ Style2 class) is also showing the datepicker as a monthpicker.

Comment: Do you have the `Style2` class on both datepickers?  Add your HTML to your question

Comment: Added my HTML and CSS relevant to the above code, thanks!

Comment: Fiddle recreation would be nice https://jsfiddle.net/ .

Comment: check out this https://jsfiddle.net/26quyed5/

Comment: @pokeybit can you elaborate this more please? If you are referring to my HMTL, the first class is placement on my HTML Table, and then the second class formats the input object.

Comment: @StefanPEev thanks for posting that! I actually did leave out the 1 critical class of CSS that is appearing to cause the conflict. I think i can perhaps figure out the rest. I'll add the additional line. The question for me is how to activate that line of CSS strictly for the #ReportPeriod object. At least now i know everything else should be fine still.